# Why would storing ASP.net sessions on MSSQL or Redis slow the web server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, session, redis

We're working towards setting up a web farm and storing sessions anywhere else but on the local state server is a required step. So I have tried 2 different options:

- Storing sessions on a redis server using `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider`
- Storing sessions on a SQL server 2014 standard edition

Both servers were dedicated to the task, in the same network than the web server and good enough spec. Each attempt only raised the CPU slightly on these servers which seems to indicate the bottleneck isn't there.

But for each attempt, changing the web.config from using the local state server to using redis or MSSQL caused the web server to be extremely sluggish and made our web site unbearably slow at times.

Some potentially useful facts:

- When using the local state server, the web server CPU averages 50% CPU
- Size of a session could be anything between 200 and 1500 Kb per user (we store a few reference tables in order to do less queries on the database)
- Our session state server currently uses 500 Mb memory at peak time
- We serve about 3,000 sessions daily, for an average time of 13 minutes per session
- Web server is a 4 vCPU 2.4GHz 16GB ram, running IIS, ASP.net 4.0
- Everything is hosted on AWS

Very happy to provide more metrics if required. Any idea why could cause it?

Comment: Do you have similar frequencies of read/write operations? Have you tried master/slave mode to separate read/write operations?

Comment: We do way more reads (at least once at every single page load or ajax request) than writes. For the Master/slave mode are you talking about failing over the session server? If so, the first attempt with Redis was indeed failed over. The second attempt with SQL wasn't.

Comment: Master/slave mode is more used in the scenario where you want to scale out your reads performance but as you said that your cache server doesn't seem to be the bottleneck. How many concurrent threads do you normally have? One session in every 13 minutes shouldn't make your CPU at 45% high.

Comment: No, 13 minutes is the average duration of a session. We have about 3,000 sessions daily, mainly occurring between 8 am and 5pm.